# Should WSASocket() be used with IOCP?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, iocp, overlapped-io

I know that it is recommended to use `WSAAccept()` instead of `accept()` when creating an IOCP application. But I am not sure if `WSASocket()` belongs to the Overlapped I/O functions, or is it just another Winsock function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always thought that you could answer this question by looking at the MSDN docs for [`socket()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`WSASocket()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and, specifically that you couldn't create a socket that can be used with overlapped I/O (and IOCPs) using `socket()` as only `WSASocket()` allows you to specify the `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag when you create the socket. But that's incorrect as `socket()` creates sockets that have `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` set.

However, in general the berkeley/POSIX sockets functions in Windows are just there as a convenience to people who want to program to that API. There's very little reason to use them and the native Windows APIs should be preferred.

Comment: Actually, the documentation for `socket()` says: "The socket that is created will have the overlapped attribute as a default".

Comment: Does it. I've never noticed that. Thanks for telling me! I've adjusted the answer

Comment: So there is no such thing as functions that only belongs to Overlapped I/O, but rather there are the `WSAxxx()` functions which can be used for Overlapped I/O, but can also be used for non Overlapped I/O. And there are the berkeley/POSIX functions which do not support Overlapped I/O. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: A socket needs to be created with the correct flag set to be usable with overlapped I/O functions in a way that results in overlapped I/O occurring. You can create a socket without the overlapped flag and pass it to WSASend() and use it for a synchronous, non overlapped send. Equally you can pass a socket WITH the overlapped flag set to WSASend() and also request a synchronous send rather than an overlapped send. What you can't do is pass a socket without the flag set and request an overlapped send. The POSIX functions do not support overlapped I/O and IOCP as these are Windows only concepts.